# why google apis show different results?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directory-api, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to get distance and duration using google direction API

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origins=latitude,longitude&destinations=latitude,longitude&&mode=driving&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

and its working fine and get the distance and duration like this

```
  distance="30 m"
  duration="1 min"
```

when am trying get distance and duration using distancematrix api,

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=latitude,longitude&destinations=latitude,longitude&&mode=driving&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
"distance" : {
                  "text" : "1.2 km",
                  "value" : 1168
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 mins",
                  "value" : 140
               }
```

Note: Passing same latitude and longitude values for both API. 
Why both API showing different results for same latitude and longitude values?

Answer (score 1):

As Google Document

[Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview#Waypoints)

Note: This service is not designed to respond in real time to user input. For dynamic directions calculations (for example, within a user interface element)

[Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)

The Google Maps Distance Matrix API is a service that provides travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations, based on the recommended route between start and end points.

Direction API may give response dynamic directions calculation i.e directions for several modes of transportation, including transit, driving, walking or cycling.

**So Result may be changed for Direction API and Distance Matrix API**

Comment: ,thank for your response,but distance matrix api results and normal map search (https://maps.google.com/) results are different.Why it happend

Comment: I tried it, and I get the same result using distance matrix api and the normal map search like you said. maybe you can give us what origin and destination that you use in your request.